# Event fire on every checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have couple of images and next to it are checkbox, that doesn't display on its own, but if click on label fire the checkbox true or false, now I thought everything was fine, until I had to use `this` so every checkbox responds to its elements, my code runs but it fire all the events for every image when one checkbox is checked.

```
 $(".suggestions").click(function() {
   if ($(".checkbox").prop('checked') === true) {
     $("h2").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(5000)
   }
   if ($(".checkbox").prop('checked') === false) {
     $("h2").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(5000)
   }
 })
```

Basically, the code when clicked on checkbox show a message of Added and when uncheck, shows a message of removed and disappear.
How can I make it work so it uses `this`? Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nofel/wxm1L824/)

Comment: label has a checked property??

Comment: @epascarello label is just a name of class, I have updated the code to show.

Comment: In what context are you using `this`? can you provide a sample of the code using it?

Comment: The code is on JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apply to every input with type checkbox, and if you also keep this structure.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $(this).parent('div').siblings('.flex-column').children('h2.addMsg').fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(5000);
    } else {
        $(this).parent('div').siblings('.flex-column').children('h2.removeMsg').fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(5000);
    }
});
```

If you have any question, let me know.

**EDIT :**

Ofcourse you could replace `input:checkbox`, with the classname `kdng`.

Comment: This worked! thanks, what was I missing or got lost?

Comment: You used selectors like `h2.removeMsg`, means that the action applies to all `h2.removeMsg`.

Comment: I am trying to understand the code, can you help me understand

Comment: Inside the function: `.on('change', function(){.....})`, I use `this`. Please look it up on the internet for the best explanation. `this` holds the current element.