# What is Difference between sibling and children

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to understand the following code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916800/event-fire-on-every-checkbox/43917404?noredirect=1#comment74868807_43917404) post, and I cannot find out why We use Children vs Siblings. I can understand Children can be following nested tag, but what is level for Siblings?

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $(this).parent('div').siblings('.flex-column').children('h2.addMsg').fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(5000);
    } else {
        $(this).parent('div').siblings('.flex-column').children('h2.removeMsg').fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(5000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sibling is not just above same level it is also about same parent. Sibling is like your brother/sister in law (same parent), you are not a sibling to your classmate.

When you click the checkbox, you are children of `div`

use `parent('div')` allowed you to target this parent,

use `.siblings('.flex-column')` will target all sibling of your parent with class `.flex-column`, then for each of those sibling go to their children find h2 with class `addMsg` or `removeMsg`.

For each do fadIn/fadeOut.

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.flex-column').children('h2.addMsg').fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(1000);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.flex-column').children('h2.removeMsg').fadeIn("fast").fadeOut(1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-column">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <h2 class="addMsg">addMsg 1</h2>
  <h2 class="removeMsg">removeMsg 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="flex-column">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <h2 class="addMsg">addMsg 2</h2>
  <h2 class="removeMsg">removeMsg 2</h2>
</div>
<span class="flex-column">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <h2 class="addMsg">addMsg 3</h2>
  <h2 class="removeMsg">removeMsg 3</h2>
</span>
```

Comment: This helped a lot. So when the code said `.parent(div)`, does it mean get me parent of the div containing `input:checkbox`? If so can I name the div passed in `parent()` to be a class too (given if it is the parent)

Comment: @Nofel it is like you are the parent now, js does not have pointer but it is like you are currently at your parent's point you are the div with children input now

Comment: @Nofel yes you don't need the `.parent('div')` just use `.parent()`

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nofel/o5ftuz3r/) is my reduce case run. I think commenting out sibling was a right step, was it? As even now my code wouldn't work.

Comment: In your example above, You have `flex-column` as a parent of the checkbox, how does it become a sibling, if it is `parent()`?

Comment: @Nofel the jsfiddle you posted you need add jQuery as lib (at JS section), also at line 6 you have `.children('h2.addMsg');` remove the `;`

Comment: @Nofel also typo at line 5 `.childern` should be `. children`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146545/discussion-between-nofel-and-daniel-h).

Answer (score 9):

Just like in real life with real families, *siblings* are elements with the same parent element.

So if we have

```
<div id=1>
  <div id=2>
  <div id=3>
  <div id=4>
</div>
```

The elements with IDs 2, 3, and 4 are all siblings of each other, and are children of element with ID 1.

Comment: Yea that is easy to understand but what in html

Comment: @Nofel I added an example.

Comment: So it depends on ID? as all have ID's, I am assuming with class, the sibling use very next?

Comment: @Nofel No, it has nothing at all to do with IDs. In the example here the three inner divs are siblings, AND they're all also children of the outer/parent div.

Comment: It has to do with the tree structure of the elements, nothing more.

Comment: Make sense, But what will be a sibling of `ID 1`, Says in some heavy html snippet.

Comment: _Any_ other element that is on the same level within the same parent will be a sibling of `ID 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Parent, siblings, children are the relations between the nodes(tags as in case of html)

**Siblings:** All the nodes which share the same parent are siblings

**Children:** All the nodes which the current node point to as parent are the Children nodes

e.g.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

- In the following example "html" is the parent node to the tags "head" and and "body".
- "head" and "body" tags are siblings to each other.
- "head" and "body" tags are children when related with the tag "html".

Answer (score 0):

In the following example of an un-ordered list, `<li>` elements are children of their parent `<ul>` element. `<li>` elements in the context of their parent `<ul>` are siblings:

```
<ul>
 <li>I am a child of my parent ul</li>
 <li>I am a sibling of the li above me</li>
 <li><span>this span is a child of this li</span></li>
</ul>
```

Deducing from your jQuery, the HTML might look something like this:

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="item">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <h2>Item header</h2>
  <p>Item content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <h2>Item header</h2>
  <p>Item content</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

When checking a checkbox the parent is the closest outer element of type div (class="item")

The jQuery chained div is returned and then further chained to find "siblings" of the same type, thus: select all divs with class="item" on the same level.

Their children are then selected and filtered on 1) type = h2 and 2) class = addMsg or removeMsg depending on checked or not.

And lastly faded in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

here `div` with class name ***parent*** and ***parent1*** is siblings to each other code here

where as ***child*** and ***child1*** is child that division